# Is an automated functionality is a Use Case?

Tags: use-case

My questions is simple as that. (In the title)

Lets see this example:

An app has a functionality:

The user can schedule an event through an API from the app. This event schedules an **alarm to be fired** on the phone. So like a simple alarm clock scheduling pulled from a server.

Is the very **function of "firing alarm"** is a **Use Case**?

It is an automated routine that will happen without the interaction of the user. (If it is already scheduled ofc)

Do I have to add this "automated alarm firing" as a **Use Case** and link it to an **Actor** in my **Use Case Diagram**?

I know that scheduling an alarm is a Use Case, and also the removing or time modification both Use Cases, **but how can I mark such an automated - no interaction needed function?**

I mean **it has to be a USAGE** of the application it does something that the user can see (hear) and make a reaction to it like do another usage, another Use Case, right? Or maybe I'am wrong,

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is a functional requirement of the system.

> Functional requirements capture the intended behavior of the system. This behavior may be expressed as
>   services, tasks or functions the system is required to perform.
>
> A use case defines a goal-oriented set of interactions between external actors and the system under consideration.

You can have a look at this article: [Functional Requirements and Use Cases](http://www.bredemeyer.com/pdf_files/functreq.pdf)